# Word resizes pictures in document?

Tags: macos, ms-office, word-processor

Whenever I add a picture to MS Word, the resolution becomes distorted along with the quality of the image. In windows, you can `reset` a picture and it will be displayed with the correct dimensions. Resetting in MS Word for Mac doesn't do that, it actually doesn't affect the picture at all.

Anyone found a way to fix this ?

Comment: Please clarify, do you mean Insert picture or Paste.

Comment: I tried either of them .. Either save a screenshot to desktop THEN move into document, or copy and paste a screenshot.

Comment: Is it only with screenshots?

Comment: Can you show an example (screenshot) of your word document (choose a public picture) to protect your privacy.

Comment: OK, lets go bit deeper. What is the version of Word? You do not use a Word Template. You view in Print layout. Is the "reset" the picture grayed out?

Comment: FYI:  Reset on my MAC works just fine, it resets the picture to original quality (after I have tinkered with it).  I know that does not help, but just to confirm that reset works.

Comment: Here, check this file out https://dl.dropbox.com/u/695335/wordfail.docx .. Reset works if I change the picture dimensions. However that;s not my problem. Word changes a picture's dimensions to fit in the document, and in Windows, pressing reset will force it to return to it's original resolution. on Mac, that doesn't happen.

Comment: ok, it opens just fine and it looks like good quality, but I might need new glases :)

Comment: Does it have anything to do with a Retina display ?? Maybe they didn't adjust picture views for Retina displays ??

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about Retina displays. But you can try importing a picture in Excel! as far I know MS office uses same drives for all they programs. Just to confirm, I have the MS Office 2011 with Word 14.3.2.

Comment: Office 2011 for Mac version **14.2.4** is now available as an update to add **Retina display support** for Word, Excel, PowerPoint and Outlook. Have you tried after this update?

Comment: I already have the update.

Comment: Is it only in Word documents or in all Office programs?

Comment: All of them, photos look blurred in all programs.

Comment: Clearly somehow the driver in MS office for your retina display is not working. Let me do some check how to verify that.